# JSON response doesn't contain "d" Anymore!!! asp.net 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, scriptservice

I have a question, we are converting asp.net 3.5 to asp.net 4.5
during this - we had many problems
but now... we finally got it too load up
now i am having strange behaviour in JSON responses from services
they don't contain "d" anymore!

```
{d: "response from server"}
```

its now

```
{"response from server"}
```

which breaks javascript code for callback any idea? or explanation

Comment: Can you provide a sample application which reproduces this behavior?  This behavior shouldn't have changed between 3.5 and 4.5, and I cannot repro it on my own box.

Comment: Here is the 4.5 Solution - You will see that there is no result.d there. You can download it here http://sdrv.ms/19z7O3q

Comment: the behavior still appears to be correct on our machines.  (MS AJAX has always unwrapped the "d" parameter before invoking the callback.)  Did anything else change in the project when you upgraded from 3.5 to 4.5?  For instance, did you take a dependency on a new JavaScript library or on a different version of an existing library?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior has changed, because Microsoft switched from using the `DataContractJsonSerializer` to Json.NET (NewtonSoft).

Comment: No I am using Asp.net Ajax in asp.net 4.5. I want to know the reason why its behavior has changed from earlier version 3.5

Answer (score -1):

If you want to name your variable when you return a result, you need to serialize it properly.

If you return a string you will get { "your string" } but if you return an object (or in 4.5 a Task of type dynamic or better yet Task of type 'Your Object') you will get your fully serialized object

```
return new { 
   result = "here is your result", 
   code  = "here is your code"
}
```

Comment: OP doesn't ask how to serialize. He/She is asking about changed behaviour.